# git diff between specific commit and local file

Tags: git

I've looked for the answer but couldn't find it on stackoverflow, so I ask it here.
Let's assume I have some local changes since the last commit(and push) and I want to git diff of a file between a specific commit(several commits ago) and my current local version.
I mean, for example, I can see the difference of a file between two specific commits by

```
git diff COMMIT1 COMMIT2 src/testsuites/file1.c
```

But I want to see the difference between COMMIT1 and local file.
How do you do that?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Per the git [docs](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff):

> git diff [--options] <commit> [--] [<path>…] This form is to view the
>   changes you have in your working tree relative to the named <commit>.
>   You can use HEAD to compare it with the latest commit, or a branch
>   name to compare with the tip of a different branch.

So you would just do `git diff COMMIT1 src/testsuites/file1.c`